# Change the style of the references

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing my thesis and I have a problem with my references.
My supervisor asked me that it should be like this:

**Author, title, journal, year (in bold), volume pp. xx-xx**

Instead of what i got:
Author, title, journal, volume, pp. xx-xx, year.

An actual MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{Nobody06,
   author = "Nobody Jr",
   title  = "My Article",
   year   = "2006"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Blablabla~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}{}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you call which style sheet you are using? Do you use the packages `natbib`, `biblatex` or similar?

Comment: I'm using ieeetr with bibtex (if i'm not mistaking)

Comment: You maybe want to change the MWE such that it better consistent with your statement.

Comment: Maybe i'm not getting it right but this doesn't change my final pdf. The year is still at the end of the reference, so like before

Comment: The [idea of a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343) is to give a short example of the issue you faced (as you do not have a solution jet)... Otherwise you could already write an answer below. ;) But please improve the example above in your sense - I do not want to dictate you anything. Its your proper question.